# Postgres remote access error

Tags: postgresql

I try to set remote access to my database, however when I set `listen_addresses = ‘*’`  and then try to restart Postgres I have error Error:

```
Invalid line 59 in /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf: 
»listen_address = ‘*’« 
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

I found this fix:
http://solutions4linux.blogspot.com/2014/09/solving-no-postgresql-clusters-exist.html
but it doesn't work. When I call `pg_createcluster 9.3 main --start` I have:

> Error: cluster configuration already exists

What's going on here?

Comment: Omg.... stupid "text edit" changed all quotes to typographical... It was very hard to see... Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use straight single quotes: `'*'`

not those "typographical" quotes `‘*’`